# Dynamic Web scraping - Chromedriver security

Tags: selenium, security

I am trying to web-scrap a dynamic page, simple urllib request gets me results from fist page only, instead of returning the whole set.

```
from urllib import request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = "https://www.olx.pl/d/nieruchomosci/mieszkania/warszawa/"
get_url = request.urlopen(URL)
get_page = get_url.read()
get_url.close()
print(get_page)
```

I was about to implement selenium and chromedriver for the dynamic webscraping, but then I read about security of this solution. Chromedriver should never be run on account with privileges, best option would be virtual machine.

As I read forum posts, almost all solutions to dynamic web scrapping involve chromedriver / selenium/ scrapy. It makes me wonder if all users set up firewall or VM to download data.

Is there any other, safer solution you would recommend for dynamic web scrapping?

Comment: What are the security threats when using selenium? I use it without VM or special firewall settings. I don't think there are other solutions, BeautifulSoup doesn't load the java elements of a webpage thus reducing the applications

Comment: https://chromedriver.chromium.org/security-considerations   , ChromeDriver should never be run with a privileged account.